# Reseting the id of the rows in sqlite database to 1

Tags: android, sqlite

I am deleting all the contents in my database with the following code

```
 db.delete("teacher_info", null, null);
```

but adding data to the same table results in the id field to increment the row id from the previous counter.
How can i set the if field to start counting from 1 after deleting the elements

Comment: It would actually count starting from 0. Anyway, you shouldn't be so concerned about the ids. Let SQLite create whichever it wants to.

Comment: i am actually creating a dynamic database so that i will need to receive data dynamically. for that i need the values to be lined in a sequential format so that i can call them squentially from a for loop

Comment: You can use a while loop (mind that ids don't necessarily match array indexes or whichever container you put them into)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command after

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + TABLE_NAME + "'");
```

Comment: should i add this after my current code or replace this with my code?

Comment: @sagar.acharya after deleting data in the table call this query with same table name. it'll reset the sequence